# Display output in the form of columnName = columnValue from a CSV file using Shell Script or awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
US,China,South Africa
1000,0,129
```

The output I'm looking for:

```
Value of US = 1000
Value of China = 0
Value of South Africa = 129
```

My CSV file has been filtered to contain only a single row apart from the row of column headings. The above statements repeat for all columns in the csv file.

Some additional information:

Firstly, the column names and values in the csv file are comma separated. The file was generated that way, and I have not modified the delimiters.

Secondly, all of my columns names are strings (may contain spaces in between), while all of my values are positive numbers (integers).

Finally, I have also crosschecked my csvfile, and every column has its corresponding value (i.e. There are no null values).

I have tried the following so far:

`csvcut -n filename.csv #To try and get the column names to iterate through them`

However, the above command returns output like:

```
1: US
2: China
3: South Africa
```

Separately, given the column name as input to my shell script, I have written

```
echo "Value of $1 = `csvcut -c $1 filename.csv`"
```

When run as `sh my_script.sh US`,

The output I get is

```
Value of US = 1000
```

I just can't figure out how to do this across all columns.

**Edit**

As the question was closed, the correct solution is found in the comments.

Credit to Ed Morton.

To others facing this issue, the solution is as below:

`awk -F, 'NR==1{split($0,h);next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "Value of", h[i], "=", $i}' file`

Comment: Since it's closed I can't post an answer but you deserve one for putting effort into fixing your question so: `awk -F, 'NR==1{split($0,h);next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "Value of", h[i], "=", $i}' file`

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{split($0,h);next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "Value of", h[i], "=", $i}' file
```